# Win32 App Compat: Is there a manifest entry to opt my application out of NoExecute?

Tags: security, winapi, manifest, fusion

Is there an assembly manifest (or perhaps a PE Image flag) to opt-out of (or opt-in to) NoExecute protection?

---

By default, Windows only protects its own binaries with NoExecute protection:

[image]

But i might want to **opt** my executable into NX protection.

i also might need to indicate to the user that my application is incompatible with NX protection. Rather than forcing the user to manually find, and add me, to a list, i can do it for them:

[image]

> **Note:** i liken this to my ability to opt-in to running my application as a standard user:
>
> ```
> <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
>   <security>
>       <requestedPrivileges>
>           <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
>       </requestedPrivileges>
>   </security>
> </trustInfo>
> ```
>
> Or the ability to opt-out of "running as standard user" protection:
>
> ```
> <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
>   <security>
>       <requestedPrivileges>
>           <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
>       </requestedPrivileges>
>   </security>
> </trustInfo>
> ```

---

**Note**: i don't *think* there is a way to opt-in, or out, of NX protection. So if the answer is **No**, that is fine. But i'm still asking because i might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can opt-in with [IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and/or SetProcessDEPPolicy)

If the system setting is not AlwaysOn (Can not be set in the GUI IIRC) then you can opt-out with [SetProcessDEPPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The parent process can force DEP with [PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_POLICY_DEP_ENABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Vista+

[Older ATL code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948468) and some 3rd party DRM/copyprotection stuff have special handling and will not be trapped by DEP when the system is in opt-out mode (Not sure about AlwaysOn)

To use "SetProcessDEPPolicy" on XP.SP2/2003.SP1 call the undocumented [NtSetInformationProcess](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/sandbox/src/dep.cc?view=markup) function.

Comment: Maybe you ought to mention Editbin.exe and its /nxcompat option.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point but not everyone uses the MS toolchain and if they do they can set the option on the command line or project settings ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235442%28v=vs.80%29.aspx )